# Unable to install ionic -g

Tags: ionic-framework

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-framework@0.1.3

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-05-10T07_52_51_175Z-debug.log

Comment: Try uninstall -g Cordova and then the install

Comment: i tried to your way but same errors @AyaAbdelaziz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solved.i uninstall nodejs and remove `.npmrc` file in C:\Users{user} and then,i reinstall nodejs.This errors is OK.

Answer (score 0):

That version of Ionic doesn't exist. Try installing from the versions listed here [NPM's Websites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic)

Then `npm install -g ionic@3.20.0` for the latest version of ionic

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have an existing version of Ionic?

Try updating your current version or:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic && sudo npm install ionic
```

Or:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli-framework@3.20.0
```

As suggested by the other user.